# Arena Chess playing with the engines

Tags: engines, arena

Can someone show me how to stop an Arena engine from showing lines that it is intending to play while we play rated games?

Answer (score 2):

Right click on the window where moves are displayed -> show/display -> click on comments.
Now the engine output should be disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Goto the menu, (at the top.) And click engines, click manage, and in the left side menu that pops up, double click all of the enabled engines to disable them!